# Why does my regex capture the surrounding characters?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to separate out path elements from a URL in ruby.  My URL is:

```
/cm/api/m_deploymentzones_getDeploymentZones.htm
```

And using a regex:

```
/\/([^\/]*)\//
```

The match is `/cm/`.  I expected to see just `cm`, given that the `/` characters are explicitly excluded from the capturing group.  What am I doing wrong?

I am also trying to get the next path element with:

```
/\/[^\/]*\/([^\/]*)\//
```

And this returns: `/cm/api/`

Any ideas?

Comment: Aren't capture groups enclosed with parentheses?

Comment: The *whole match* will be `/cm/` but the *group 1* will be `cm`. I guess you have an API problem. Besides, why don't you just split the string on `/` ?

Comment: `/\/([^\/]*)\//.match(s)[1]`, `/\/[^\/]*\/([^\/]*)\//.match(s)[1]`

Comment: is this what you want? `\/(\w+)\/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to use [`URI.parse()`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-parse):

```
require 'uri'

url = '/cm/api/m_deploymentzones_getDeploymentZones.htm'
parts = URI.parse(url).path.split('/') # ["", "cm", "api", "m_deploymentzones_getDeploymentZones.htm"]
```

Comment: Who says he's using Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex matching the path components:

`(?<=/).+?(?=/|$)`

But you'd be better off just splitting the string on `/` characters. You don't need regex for this.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `(?<=\/).+?(?=\/)`?  E.g., `"/cm/api/m_dep.htm".scan /(?<=\/).+?(?=\/)/ #=> ["cm", "api"]`?  This of course does check the validity of the format, e.g, `s = "/####/x"`, `s.scan /(?<=\/).+?(?=\/)/ #=> ["####"]`, whereas `URI.parse(s) #=> URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I posted the raw regex expression, where `/` is not a special character and does not need to be escaped. Of course, when you use `/` as a regex literal delimiter you'll have to escape the `/` characters in the regex, but in this case I'd advise choosing another delimiter, because the less escaping you need to do the better it is for legibility. I don't know ruby but I've looked up you can use the following syntax for literals: `%r{REGEX}`. With this syntax `/` wouldn't need to be escaped. I didn't test it in ruby, but that's the way it works in Perl (with the `m{REGEX}` syntax).